# text box not showing value being set

Tags: jquery

Here's my jquery:

```
success : function(resp){
      if(resp){
        // set the zipcode so the user doesn't have to enter it
          console.log('setting the zipcode to ' + resp);
          $("#zipcode").val(resp);
          console.log('and now zipcode is ' + $('#zipcode').val());
      }},
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" required />
```

The first console.log shows a very nice 90210.  The second console.log tells me the textbox has the correct value of 90210, but the text box is visually empty.  What gives?

Comment: have you tried .text(resp)

Comment: @Charles380 when i tried that, it didn't work and the 2nd console.log didn't have the value either :(

Comment: What kind of element is #zipcode ? with textboxes val() should work

Comment: looks like you might have multiple elements with the id `zipcode`

Comment: Try `console.log('ID Test:', $('[id=zipcode]').length, $('[id=zipcode]').get())`

Comment: @ArunPJohny this is the second time you've helped me!!!  You win the prize for being correct.  I DID have another zipcode on the page.  Add your answer and I'll choose it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the what is given, it looks like there are multiple element with the same id in the page...

So the id selector is returning the first element with the id `zipcode` which is not your input element. So remove the duplicate IDs to fix the problem.

To find out if there is actually duplicate ids use the following logging statement

```
console.log('ID Test:', $('[id=zipcode]').length, $('[id=zipcode]').get())
```